# Smooth maps preserve dimension

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I stumbled over a useful consequence, that is apparently wrong for only continuous maps.
Imagine $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is a compact set and $F : \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \rightarrow S^{n}$ a smooth map, then we cannot have $F(A) = S^{n}.$ In other words: Smooth maps must preserve the dimension somehow.

Does anybody know how to show this?

Answer (score 4):

This is a consequence of [Sard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem). Since $\dim\Bbb R^{n-1}<\dim S^n$, a map $F:\Bbb R^{n-1}\to S^{n}$ has critical values everywhere and hence its image $F(\Bbb R^{n-1})$ has measure zero in $S^n$.

This is not true in general for continuous functions, for example because of the existence of [space filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) $\Bbb R\to S^2$.

Comment: It is a bit overkill for showing preservation of dimension. You can just use the invertibility of the Jacobian matrix or the invertibility of the differential of $F$.

Comment: @Hans could you elaborate on how to use the invertibility of the Jacobian or the differential? Thank you!

Comment: @Hans Invertibility of the differential would shows that $F$ **locally** preserves the dimension, but it woud not show that the whole image cannot be $S^n$

Comment: Smoothness does not imply invertibility of the Jacobian, not even locally. It just implies that the dimension of the image can not exceed the dimension of the domain. Thus, one can not make use of the invertibility of the Jacobian here.